# Ideas for converting Android App project to pure java for desktop

Tags: java, android

I have a huge Android app project, I attempt to convert it to pure Java, I think to include all classes that my new app need it like `View` , `TextView`, `Activity` , etc. I can get it from Android framework source code.
I know this idea will increase my app size, but it will save a lot of time and efforts 
**My Question: How successful that idea?**

Comment: Would not work.  Android uses Dalvic VM on top of JVM..

Comment: The implementation of those classes depend on native code. If there were a pure java implementation of those classes it could form an applet like environment for running android applications but it would be limited to those that you have the source or class files for as it couldn't run classes that were already converted to a dalvik dex.

Answer (score 1):

You should look into ARC:
  https://developer.chrome.com/apps/getstarted_arc

This is a Android Runtime for chrome on desktops

Comment: I thing ARC uses the VM box like genymotion and Android x86, I want to build my own framework use the same code of android and run on any PC

Comment: No ARC is not a emulator like genymotion - ARC is a runtime and this is what you might want - sure you can roll your own but this is a lot of work and will only be successful when you have a lot of time/resources